# Repeated error: "Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer supported" with phpmyadmin

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin

The following error is in my `/var/log/apache2/error.log` file. I can not access the `index.php` file or any other phpmyadmin file, in replace of phpmyadmins interface my server returns an http 500 error. All other files work fine, its only phpmyadmin's which has this issue.

```
Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer supported in /usr/share/$
$share/phpmyadmin/libraries/Util.php on line 2087
```

I know what this error means and how to fix it but after I fix it a new issue arises with the exact same error, just in a different place, I go to the file to fix it and this process has repeated for around 15 minutes now of just checking logs, replacing, repeat. Is there any quicker way to fix this?

PHP Version: 8.0.12

Update: I have tried updating phpmyadmin and php but the issue persists.

Comment: What version of PHPMyAdmin are you using? it sounds like you need to update that

Comment: `4.6.6-5`
I uninstalled and reinstalled phpmyadmin but it appears that this for some reason hasnt downloaded the latest version. I see on their website the latest version is 5.1.1 and when I download this it downloads a zip. Where can I place this zip file in order to replace my current version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your phpMyAdmin version, 4.6.6, was released in 2017 and is quite old. In fact, it doesn't work with any PHP newer than 7.1, which is probably the cause of your problems.

You'll need to download the newer version and uncompress the file in to your web root folder (depending on your distribution and web server, `/var/www/phpmyadmin` or `/var/www/html/phpmyadmin` are likely locations, although of course you can tweak the folder name based on your preference).

https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#quick-install has more information about manually installing phpMyAdmin.